# Function not firing first time around

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working with Kendo controls (specifically `Grid` and `Drop Down Lists`).

As there is no built in handler on the Kendo Grid components for double click events, I have coded some JQuery to get around this.

From inspecting the browser console, I can see the double click event being triggered as well as the relevant data item being extracted from the grid.

The issue lies with `applySelections` called from within the double click function. I want to pre-select values from the six Kendo Drop Downs based on the data on the row selected. Following this, I trigger the `change` event on each drop down list to apply the relevant filters.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.tbody.on("dblclick", "tr", function (e) {
        var test = grid.dataItem(this);
        applySelections(grid.dataItem(this));            
    });

    function applySelections(item) {
        $('#ddl1').data('kendoDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.ID === item.subItems[0].ID;
        });
        $('#ddl2').data('kendoDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.ID === item.subItems[1].ID;
        });
        $('#ddl3').data('kendoDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.ID === item.subItems[2].ID;
        });
        $('#ddl4').data('kendoDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.ID === item.subItems[3].ID;
        });
        $('#ddl5').data('kendoDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.ID === item.subItems[4].ID;
        });
        $('#ddl6').data('kendoDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.ID === item.subItems[5].ID;
        });

        $("#ddl1").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
        $("#ddl2").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
        $("#ddl3").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
        $("#ddl4").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
        $("#ddl5").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
        $("#ddl6").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
    }
}
```

On the first double click, I have traced the code and can see the initial double click function being executed.  However, none of the `select` events within the `applySelections` function are being triggered.  Next time around, the same code is executed for each drop down and the expected results are observed.

Comment: Good work so ... upvote for you...

Comment: Excellent work so far.. Keep it up, U will get there #believe  (Upvote for you)

Comment: Fantastic Job lab. Keep 'er lit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further inspection, the solution turned out to be relatively straight forward (and obvious).  The Drop Down controls `autoBind` value was set to `false` which meant my `select` events had nothing to `select`.

Changing:

```
var ddl1 = $("#ddl1").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false
    ...
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

to:

```
var ddl1 = $("#ddl1").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: true
    ...
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

for each of the Drop Down controls forced the `dataSource` to be populated on page load.

I am surprised that I didn't receive any web browser errors when trying to select an element which did not yet exist.